# How to reconstruct data from 10 components in Python using 2 matrixes after PCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Help please!!
I've seen some anawers here, but they didn't help me. I need to reconstruct the initial data, having 2 matrixes and using first ten principal components. First matrix (Z) (X_reduced_417)- result of applying sklearn.decomposition.PCA. Second matrix (X_loadings_417) (F) is weight matrix. Answer is Initial data = Z*F+mean_matrix. How to use sklearn to find Z?

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets, sklearn.decomposition

df_loadings = pd.read_csv('X_loadings_417.csv', header=None)
df_reduced = pd.read_csv('X_reduced_417.csv', header=None) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load the df_loadings and df_reduced matrices from the CSV files
df_loadings = pd.read_csv("X_loadings_417.csv", header=None)
df_reduced = pd.read_csv("X_reduced_417.csv", header=None)

# Convert the DataFrames to numpy arrays
F = df_loadings.values
Z = df_reduced.values

# The mean of the original data is needed to reconstruct the data
mean_matrix = np.mean(X, axis=0)

# Reconstruct the original data using the first ten principal components
X_reconstructed = Z[:,:10].dot(F[:10,:]) + mean_matrix
```

Comment: There are a few problems: 1) we don't have X 2) And we cannot do Z[:,:10].dot(F[:10,:])? because shapes (100,1) and (10,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0).